# What is the purpose of this if statement from "Learning Python the Hard Way"?

Tags: python

I am currently reading *Learning Python the Hard Way* and I have a question regarding one line of the following code.

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York' 
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (Enter to quit)"
    state = raw_input(">")

#This is the line I have question for
    if not state: break

    city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
    print city_found
```

1. I would like to know the purpose of this line since the code can run without an error even when I deleted this line.
2. It seems like there's no condition that will ever make the program run this line, as I tried to put a `print` statement before `break` and it never got printed.

Comment: Have you tried simply pressing enter without entering a state, with and without the `if ... break` statement?

Comment: If there was no value given to the state, then the while loop will break abruptly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you are indeed correct. When I tried to press Enter, it exited the program completely. But when I deleted the line and pressed Enter, it ran the find_city function and returned Not Found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty string is considered a falsey value. Therefore, `if not state:` means that the content of that block will be evaluated when `state` is an empty string (or any other falsey value). The `break` ends the loop early.

What this does is exit the loop immediately when the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering any text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you are indeed correct. When I tried to press Enter, it exited the program completely. But when I deleted the line and pressed Enter, it ran the find_city function and returned Not Found.

Comment: @YAL - *" I deleted the line and pressed Enter, it ran the find_city function and returned Not Found"* - which is the expected behaviour because there is no state that matches the empty string.